# Javascript - Error when i inject a function from external file in angularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

right now I am trying to upload a file in an Azure's blob using angularJS and C# for back-end. I searched around and I find this [post on GitHub](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and I wanted to try. The problem is, after I link the js file in index.html when I try do inject 'Upload' as he told me to do I get

> Error: [$injector:unpr]

What should I do? Here is my code:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('mainApp').controller('maketestController', ['dataContext', 'Upload', function (dataContext, Upload) {

      ...
      ...

    }]);
})();
```

and a pic with my index.html

[image]

Comment: did you inject the module in the main app? `angular.module('mainApp', ['ngFileUpload'])`

Comment: Yea, that was, thank you